# how is the rank of a skew map is even ?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, transpose, skew-mapping

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Greub, at page 230, it is claimed that

> More general, it will now be shown that the rank of a skew
>   transformation is always even. Since every skew mapping is normal (see
>   sec. S.5) the image space is the orthogonal complement of the kernel.
>   Consequently, the induced transformation $\psi_1 : Im(\psi) \to
>  Im(\psi)$ is regular. Since $\psi_1$ is again skew, it follows that
>   the dimension of $Im(\psi)$ must be even. It follows from this result
>   that the rank of a skew-symmetric matrix is always even.

However, I cannot understand how does the fact that the dimension of $im(\psi)$ should be even follow from his argument.

**Note that, I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/rank-of-skew-symmetric-matrix/7985#7985) answer, but if works on a complex space, and I'm particularly interested in understanding the Greub's argument.**

Comment: Apparently, the author has a previous result "regular + skew implies even-dimensional" at hand?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Not really. Skew mapping are mentioned first at page 229, and this is mentioned at 230, and between those lines, we only definitions.

Comment: A skew-symmetric matrix of odd size has determinant zero, since $\det(A)=\det(A^t)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n \det(A)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark yes, I do know that, but how does this helps ?

Comment: Regular = nonsingular = (determinant is not zero).

Comment: @HansLundmark yes, I do know that too, but how can we connect this fact with the even / odd character of the dimension ?

Comment: The dimension of the image space can't be odd, since in that case the determinant of $\psi_1$ would have to be zero (according to my previous comment). Which it isn't, since $\psi_1$ is regular.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, you are right, I advise you to convert your comments in to an answer. Thanks a lot by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A skew-symmetric linear transformation on an odd-dimensional space has determinant zero and is therefore not regular. So since $\psi_1 \colon \operatorname{Im}(\psi) \to \operatorname{Im}(\psi)$ is skew-symmetric and regular, the space $\operatorname{Im}(\psi)$ must be even-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

While Greub is not as determinant-phobic as Axler, my impression is that he also would rather not resort to a determinantal argument if possible. What he had in mind probably goes like this: as $\psi_1^\ast\psi_1$ is self-adjoint, it has an eigenpair $(\lambda,u)$. Let $v=\psi_1(u)$. Since $\psi_1$ is skew and regular, we have $u\perp v\ne0$. Yet $\psi_1(v)=-\lambda u$ and $\psi_1^\ast\psi_1(v)=\lambda v$. Therefore $u$ and $v$ are two mutually orthogonal eigenvectors of $\psi_1^\ast\psi_1$ and they also span a two-dimensional invariant subspace of $\psi_1$. Proceed recursively, we see that $Im(\psi_1)$ is a direct sum of two-dimensional invariant subspaces, each spanned by two eigenvectors of $\psi_1^\ast\psi_1$. Hence it is even-dimensional.

Comment: By the way, that is a nice proof :) Thanks a lot sir.